# global name 'distance' is not defined

Tags: python, ros

I'm new to python and ros, and I'm having a little issue at the moment. I'm sure it's a simple error on my part, but I can't figure it out.

I've searched and found similar situations, but I'm not sure how to implement the solutions given to other answers on my code.

Please ignore any 'crappiness' in my code that does not directly contribute to the issue.  I just need this project to run as quickly as possible.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist, Vector3Stamped
from math import radians
from sensor_msgs.msg import NavSatFix
import geometry_msgs.msg
import time
import numpy

global distance
global pub
global dest_lat
global dest_long
global move_cmd
global turn_cmd
global bearing
global heading
global initial_bearing
global cur_lat
global prev_lat
global cur_long
global prev_long

bearing = 0

################################################################################
lat_dest = 30.210406
#                                                   DESTINATION COORDINATES
long_dest = -92.022914
################################################################################

move_cmd = Twist()
turn_cmd = Twist()

def nav_dist(navsat):
    R = 6373000        # Radius of the earth in m
    cur_lat = navsat.latitude
    cur_long = navsat.longitude
    dLat = cur_lat - lat_dest
    dLon = cur_long - long_dest
    x = dLon * numpy.cos((lat_dest+cur_lat)/2)
    distance = numpy.sqrt(x**2 + dLat**2) * R
    return distance


def bearing():
    if (bearing == 0):
        bearing = initial_bearing
        return bearing
    else:
        bearing = calculate_bearing(cur_lat, prev_lat, cur_long, prev_long)
        return bearing


def calculate_bearing(lat1, lat2, long1, long2):
    dLon = long2 - long1
    y = np.sin(dLon) * np.cos(lat2)
    x = np.cos(lat1)*np.sin(lat2) - np.sin(lat1)*np.cos(lat2)*np.cos(dLon)
    bearing = (np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(y, x)) + 360) % 360
    return bearing

def calculate_nav_angle(lat1, lat_dest, long1, long_dest):
    dLon = long_dest - long1
    y = np.sin(dLon) * np.cos(lat_dest)
    x = np.cos(lat1)*np.sin(lat_dest) - np.sin(lat1)*np.cos(lat_dest)*np.cos(dLon)
    heading = (np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(y, x)) + 360) % 360
    return heading

def navigate(distance, nav_angle):
    turn_cmd.angular.z = radians(bearing - heading)
    move_cmd.linear.x = distance
    pub.publish(turn_cmd)
    time.sleep(.01)
    pub.publish(move_cmd)
    time.sleep(.001)

    prev_long = cur_long
    prev_lat = cur_lat

###############################################################################################

#################################    callbacks and run    #################################

###############################################################################################

def call_nav(navsat):
    rospy.loginfo("Latitude: %s", navsat.latitude)      #Print GPS co-or to terminal
    rospy.loginfo("Longitude: %s", navsat.longitude)
    nav_dist(navsat)
    time.sleep(.001)


def call_bear(bearing):
    rospy.loginfo("Bearing: %s", bearing.vector)            #Print mag reading for bearing
    x = -bearing.vector.y
    y = bearing.vector.z
    initial_bearing = numpy.arctan2(y, x)
    return initial_bearing

def run():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/husky_velocity_controller/cmd_vel', Twist)
    rospy.Subscriber("/imu_um6/mag", Vector3Stamped, call_bear)
    rospy.Subscriber("/gps/fix", NavSatFix, call_nav)
    rospy.init_node('navigate_that_husky')

    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
    navigate(distance, nav_angle)
```

and here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NewTest.py", line 111, in <module>
    navigate(distance, nav_angle)
NameError: global name 'distance' is not defined
```

how might I fix this?  I appreciate any help.

Comment: You're never giving any value to `distance` before that line. A `global` statement does not set a value to variable. Actually when executed in the module scope as in your code, it does not do anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function you are redefining your global variable `distance` as a local one

Comment: Thanks.  A friend pointed that out to me just now.

Answer (score 0):

In python, `global` does not mark variable as global; `global` goes inside a function to allow the function to modify the variable.

For example:

```
def eggs():
    x = 5 #<- local variable
    print(x)

x = 10 #<- top-level variable
eggs() #<- prints 5
print(x) #<- prints 10 because the function doesn't touch the top-level variable
```

However:

```
def eggs():
    global x
    x = 5 #<- modify the top level variable
    print(x)

x = 10 #<- top-level variable
eggs() #<- prints 5
print(x) #<- prints 5 because now the function can modify the top-level veriable
```